# jquery plugin properly applied on hover but not on hidden element

Tags: jquery

I am trying to apply a plugin but facing some problem.
Here is the code

```
$('.shuffle').one('mouseenter', function () {
    $(this).BlocksIt({
        numOfCol: 4,
        offsetX: 8,
        offsetY: -18,
        blockElement: '.grid'
    });
})
```

And i am calling it like this

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $('.shuffle').each(function (i) {
        var self = this
        $(self).trigger('mouseenter')
    })
})
```

I am creating a menu. Here is an image demonstration.

[image]

After mouseenter this becomes like this

[image]

You see the difference it removes the white spaces and arranges the blocks in a proper order. The problem is that i want to do it on page load so that i dont have to drag mouse on each menu item so that its child are arranged.

Here is what i am facing after each method.

[image]

You see the grid class inside each shuffle classes messes up.

Here is my code like. i am posting some sample cos my code is quite complex. This is basically working on shuffle class.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 shuffle" style="height: 335px;">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 grid" style="width: 231.5px; left: 0px; top: -18px; position: absolute;">
            <h2 class="title">Armoires &amp; Bookcases</h2>
            <ul class="links">
                    <li><a href="category-v1.html">Showcases/ Displays</a></li>
                    <li><a href="category-v1.html">Bookcases</a></li>
                    <li><a href="category-v1.html">Armoires</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 grid" style="width: 231.5px; left: 277.5px; top: -18px; position: absolute;">
            <h2 class="title">Carts &amp; Stands</h2>
            <ul class="links">
                    <li><a href="category-v1.html">Carts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="category-v1.html">Stands</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 grid" style="width: 231.5px; left: 832.5px; top: -18px; position: absolute;">
            <h2 class="title">Filing, Storage &amp; Accessories</h2>
            <ul class="links">
                    <li><a href="category-v1.html">Lateral Files</a></li>
                    <li><a href="category-v1.html">Fire Resistant File Cabinets &amp; Safes</a></li>
                    <li><a href="category-v1.html">File Cabinet Accessories</a></li>
                    <li><a href="category-v1.html">Art &amp; Drafting Files</a></li>
                    <li><a href="category-v1.html">Shelving</a></li>
                    <li><a href="category-v1.html">Overfiles &amp; Tops</a></li>
                    <li><a href="category-v1.html">Mobile Files &amp; Carts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="category-v1.html">Literature Organizers/Sorters/Racks</a></li>
                    <li><a href="category-v1.html">Shelving Accessories</a></li>
                    <li><a href="category-v1.html">Storage Cabinets &amp; Lockers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="category-v1.html">Vertical Files</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</div>


<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 shuffle" style="height: 0px;">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 grid" style="width: 9px; left: 0px; top: -18px; position: absolute;">
            <h2 class="title">Binders &amp; Accessories</h2>
            <ul class="links">
                    <li><a href="category-v1.html">Binders</a></li>
                    <li><a href="category-v1.html">Binder Accessories</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 grid" style="width: 9px; left: 0px; top: -54px; position: absolute;">
            <h2 class="title">Boards &amp; Easels</h2>
            <ul class="links">
                    <li><a href="category-v1.html">Boards</a></li>
                    <li><a href="category-v1.html">Board Accessories</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 grid" style="width: 9px; left: 0px; top: -198px; position: absolute;">
            <h2 class="title">Desk Organizers</h2>
            <ul class="links">
                    <li><a href="category-v1.html">Desk Organizers &amp; Holders</a></li>
                    <li><a href="category-v1.html">Desktop Computer Accessories</a></li>
                    <li><a href="category-v1.html">Bookends &amp; Book Shelves</a></li>
                    <li><a href="category-v1.html">Wall Organizers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="category-v1.html">Desktop Organizers &amp; Holders</a></li>
                    <li><a href="category-v1.html">Desktop Organizer Accessories</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 grid" style="width: 9px; left: 0px; top: -234px; position: absolute;">
            <h2 class="title">Filing Supplies</h2>
            <ul class="links">
                    <li><a href="category-v1.html">Medical Filing</a></li>
                    <li><a href="category-v1.html">Folders</a></li>
                    <li><a href="category-v1.html">Filing Accessories</a></li>
                    <li><a href="category-v1.html">Jackets</a></li>
                    <li><a href="category-v1.html">Hanging Folders</a></li>
                    <li><a href="category-v1.html">Report Covers &amp; Portfolios</a></li>
                    <li><a href="category-v1.html">File Folders</a></li>
                    <li><a href="category-v1.html">Expanding Files</a></li>
                    <li><a href="category-v1.html">Guides</a></li>
                    <li><a href="category-v1.html">Folder Frames and Sorters</a></li>
                    <li><a href="category-v1.html">End Tab Folders / Medical</a></li>
                    <li><a href="category-v1.html">Classification Folders</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 grid" style="width: 9px; left: 0px; top: -270px; position: absolute;">
            <h2 class="title">Envelopes &amp; Forms</h2>
            <ul class="links">
                    <li><a href="category-v1.html">Forms &amp; Certificates</a></li>
                    <li><a href="category-v1.html">Envelopes</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 grid" style="width: 9px; left: 0px; top: -306px; position: absolute;">
            <h2 class="title">General Supplies</h2>
            <ul class="links">
                    <li><a href="category-v1.html">Paper Punch Accessories</a></li>
                    <li><a href="category-v1.html">Pad Holders</a></li>
                    <li><a href="category-v1.html">Magnification</a></li>
                    <li><a href="category-v1.html">Indexing Flags &amp; Tabs</a></li>
                    <li><a href="category-v1.html">Clocks</a></li>
                    <li><a href="category-v1.html">Clips, Tacks &amp; Rubber Bands</a></li>
                    <li><a href="category-v1.html">Books</a></li>
                    <li><a href="category-v1.html">Badges &amp; Holders</a></li>
                    <li><a href="category-v1.html">Scissors, Rulers &amp; Paper Trimmers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="category-v1.html">Paper Punches</a></li>
                    <li><a href="category-v1.html">Stamps &amp; Pads Accessories</a></li>
                    <li><a href="category-v1.html">Signs &amp; Nameplates</a></li>
                    <li><a href="category-v1.html">Staplers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="category-v1.html">Stapler Accessories</a></li>
                    <li><a href="category-v1.html">Tape, Glue &amp; Adhesives</a></li>
                    <li><a href="category-v1.html">Tags &amp; Tickets</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</div>
```

Reference to plugin. [BlocksIt](http://www.inwebson.com/jquery/blocksit-js-dynamic-grid-layout-jquery-plugin/)

Note : One problem is that when i remove load code i just use this code

```
$('.shuffle').one('mouseenter', function () {
    $(this).BlocksIt({
        numOfCol: 4,
        offsetX: 8,
        offsetY: -18,
        blockElement: '.grid'
    });
})
```

Now when user brings his pointer to furniture it displays the unarranged blocks under furniture then user brings the pointer inside shuffle class and all the things are arranged. This means unless the section under is not displayed the plugin is not applied. Any idea how i can fix this problem?

Comment: In my opinion you don't need a jQuery plugin to do that, since your content is static. I think the problem comes from the fact that you are styling some content on hover. The only thing that should change on hover in your css is the `display` property, in your case.

Comment: Can you please create jsfiddle for the same? so that I can check the exact issue.

Comment: Give the css files too, upload your project on github and then i can fix this whole thing for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i have done it using this method.
Created a css class

```
.dropdown-display {
    display:block;
}
```

Then found out the parent which is hiding the div

```
var $selector = $(this).parents().eq(3);
```

And here is the last code

```
$('.shuffle').each(function () {
    var self = this;
    var $selector = $(this).parents().eq(3);
    $selector.addClass('dropdown-display');
    $(self).BlocksIt({
        numOfCol: 4,
        offsetX: 8,
        offsetY: -18,
        blockElement: '.grid'
    })
    $selector.removeClass('dropdown-display');
})
```

## Most Important Notes

One thing to be noted why i have used a class instead of simple

```
$selector.css({display:'block'})
```

and then removing

```
$selector.css({display:'none'})
```

Because it adds a style property inline on element like this.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu fadeInUp animatedfadeInUpanimated" style="display:block">

<ul class="dropdown-menu fadeInUp animatedfadeInUpanimated" style="display:none">
```

Once property is added the style attribute inside a class will never be called.
When i add class it overrides `display:none` property of class dynamically. And removing the class will then reset the default behavior.

Hope this last information is useful to many.

Answer (score 0):

First, the source code you posted has `style` attributes on it. Remove those.

Then, get rid of BlocksIt and use [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) instead. Why? Because I already know how to use Masonry.

In your posted source code you've got two levels of `div`s. This looks like an error to me. You should have one "parent" `div` that contains all your children `div`s.

Here is my solution: http://jsbin.com/gixuhu

```
<head>
<style>
    /* REQUIRED FOR MASONRY TO WORK! */
    .masonry > div{width:230px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- SEE JSBIN LINK ABOVE FOR HTML -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/3.3.2/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        // ProTip: if you put your masonry code AFTER the elements that need it you can fire it off without waiting for `document.ready`
        $(".masonry").masonry();
        // not the most performant solution, but it should work.
        $(".hover").on("mouseover", function(){
            $(".masonry").masonry({
                transitionDuration: 0
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: even with masonary the same issue

Comment: yes i checked it but on load it displays while my menu is hidden and displayed only on hover

Answer (score 0):

Issue happen because `BlocksIt` does not work correctly with `invisible` element

Try something like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".furniture-menu").mouseenter(function(){
        $(".shuffle-parent-has-display-is-hidden").show();
        $(".shuffle").BlocksIt({
            numOfCol: 4,
            offsetX: 8,
            offsetY: -18,
            blockElement: '.grid'
        });
        $(".menu").off("mouseenter");
    });
})
```